# Slope of a line which is both tangent and normal to a given curve

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If a line is tangent to one point and normal to another point on the curve $x=4t^2+3$,$y=8t^3-1$ then the question is to find out the slope of such a line.

---

Slope of curve at $(4t_1^2+3,8t_1^3-1)$ is $3t_1$.Now it is normal to the curve at point $t_2$,then slope of normal at that point is $\frac{-1}{3t_2}$.Equating we get $9t_1t_2=-1$.I couldn't proceed after this.Any help shall be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You know the slope of that line and the intersection point with the curve. You will get that the equation of the same line is written in terms of $t_1$ and $t_2$, giving you a system with two equations. Precisely, the line has equation $y-(8t_1^3-1)=(3t_1)(x-(4t_1^2+3))$, but it also has equation $y-(8t_2^3-1)=(-1/3t_2)(x-(4t_2^2+3))$. Equate coefficients to get the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation of the tangent at the point $(4t^2+3,8t^3-1)$ is $$y-8t^3+1=3t(x-4t^2-3)$$

The tangent meets the curve again at $P(4p^2+3,8p^3-1)$ so substitute these coordinates into the tangent equation and we get, after cancellation, $$8p^3-8t^3=3t(4p^2-4t^2)$$

This can be simplified and factorised easily since we know that, due to tangency, $(p-t)^2$ must be a factor, and the only other solution is $$p=-\frac t2$$

The tangent is also the normal at $P$ so $$3p=-\frac{1}{3t}$$

Eliminating $p$ gives $$t=\pm\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}$$ so the possible gradients are $$\pm\sqrt{2}$$